# In nebular how to apply routerLink to the user dropdown

Tags: angular-routerlink, nebular

I would like to add a link for a dropdown coded using nb-action loaded from the controller.

[Check the screenshot here](http://prntscr.com/lmmdhw)

I tried adding routerLink or link in the paramas but no luck.
`userMenu = [{ title: 'Profile' }, { title: 'Log out' , link: '/login'}];`

Coding at angular6, using ngx-theme and nebular

Comment: Hi Guys, the about `link: '/login'` is working. I just did not have a routing for /login and mistaken for not linking. Also I like to admit, nebular doc does not say we got to be using link or routerLink, it was purely a guess. I leave the question as it is as it might be useful for other.

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer in other page but in short it is this way.

```
constructor(menu: NbMenuService) {
this.menu.onItemClick().subscribe(e => {
      console.log(e.item);
    });
}
```

I hope it helps you, regards. The documentation is very little